# Big space of nothingness on my website

Tags: html, css

I've developed a website using CSS and HTML code. I think it looks great. It's responsive, it has a sleek design, and it's interactive.

However, I've ran into a little problem. When I scroll down, there is a big space of absolutely nothing just sitting there. I've tried adding content to this space, but when I do, the space just runs off below the content. I have no idea what's causing this big space of nothingness, so I was hoping you guys could help.

Picture of the problem:
[Space problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGxgz.png)

So, as you can see, if you look at the top, that's the finishing content. After that content, I just want that to complete the bottom portion of my website. However, for some reason, it shows a big space of the black background on my website, and I don't know how to get rid of it. Could somebody please help me?

The full source code of my website can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/4EpMLtq7

(The fonts might look weird though if you don't have some of them installed.)

Thanks!

Comment: Put your code inside of a fiddle so that we can see what is rendered: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3):

Your last element has `position: relative; top: -344px;`, so there's 344px of empty, unoccupied space at the end - what did you expect?

Try removing all of that positioning nonsense (`float: 50%`, wtf?) and suddenly you'll see that [everything fits together](https://jsfiddle.net/zz3ctda0/) as it should.

Comment: If the image is supposed to be behind the title text, have you tries using `background-image` instead of an `<img>` tag?

Comment: I only used the background command with colors in the CSS (background-color:). And that's only for the background of the website, which is black.

Shall I try to use the background-image command for the introductory image behind the title?

Comment: The <img> tag has a width + height limit implemented to it, so this shouldn't be the cause of the big gap below the website. I'm not sure if it's that image that's causing the problem because the big gap below is completely black, and there isn't any presence of the image there. Something must have been stretched out to cause the gap, which is what I'm trying to fix.

Sorry I offended you though. I'm going to try to use the background-image right now, and I'll see how it turns out.